# YAML Script Handelers

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have two files in root folder. ie. `index.php` and `signup.php` and the `app.yaml` looks like this,

```
application: testcboy
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /img
  static_dir: img

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Problem is, when the link of `singup.php` from the home page (`index.php`) is cliked, then only the url of address bar is changes but page remains the same home page(`index.php`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Script_handlers)?

```
- url: /signup.php
  script: signup.php

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

or if you have lots of scripts you want to route to you could use something like

```
- url: /(.*)\.php
  script: \1.php

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Comment: Thank you very much and yeah i read the documents but i was writing it like this

`- url: /.*
  script: index.php

- url: /signup.php
  script: signup.php`